# add parameter to links on page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add let's say something like `ajax=1` to all links on my page with jquery. I will also need to check if the url has existing parameters. for example `http://example.com/index.php?pl=132` will have to become `http://example.com/index.php?pl=132&ajax=1`

Also, if the link does not have any parameters, for example `http://example.com/index.php`, it will become `http://example.com/index.php?ajax=1` I want to load the jQuery script on document ready so all links are changed on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in plugins, there's the jQuery [Query String Object](https://github.com/alrusdi/jquery-plugin-query-object). This will allow you simple checking of parameters in the querystring, and  if necessary the ability to add more, remove some, or edit others.

Comment: This isn't what he's looking for.

Comment: @SLaks I disagree. This accomplishes what you offered, but wrapped in a plugin and less-verbose. You can check to see if a parameter exists, if not, add it, etc.

Comment: Can this modify existing hyperlinks?

Comment: @SLaks Yes. I suppose I should say instead that *you* can modify existing links with it.

Comment: this looks real interesting. but how do I ask the plugin to change all links on page?

Comment: @Priyo By cycling through all links on the page as demonstrated in the other answers here. You can do this via `$.each()` or by using a function on the `$.attr()` method to return a modified version of the link's url.

Answer (score 58):

You could do something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $("a").attr('href', function(i, h) {
     return h + (h.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&ajax=1" : "?ajax=1");
   });
});
```

On `document.ready` this looks at every `<a>`, looks at it's href, if it contains `?` already it appends `&ajax=1` if it doesn't, it appends `?ajax=1`.

Comment: Except for `/weird/page.aspx?`.  Also, this won't work for named anchors.

Comment: @SLaks - The problem is the initial rendering of the link in that case, not jQuery...

Comment: AFAIK, that's a legal (but very unlikely) URL.

Comment: @SLaks - I agree, I'm hoping since the OP has `mysite.com` they have rendering control over the links and wouldn't be doing that :)  Maybe personal preference, but I just wouldn't want/like to have links in that fashion.

Comment: It will still fail for named anchors, though.

Comment: @SLaks - As would both of ours on something like `page.php#home`, but that isn't what the OP asked, he wants to append this to every link.

Comment: tested the script out. named anchors fail. links like "mysite.com/wiki/something" dont get appended....

Comment: @Priyo - This works for links like that, see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/xDvEx/  Maybe you have something else going on in the page interfering?

Comment: links which are coded tis way: <a title="The Canon of Medicine" href="/wiki/The_Canon_of_Medicine"> remain unchanged

Comment: @Priyo - Those works too, see the updated example to include it: http://jsfiddle.net/xDvEx/4/ If these aren't working for you, something *else* is happening in your page.

Comment: This is awesome. Exactly what I needed. Thats @NickCraver

Comment: short and simple, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href]').attr('href', function(index, href) {
        var param = "key=value";

        if (href.charAt(href.length - 1) === '?') //Very unlikely
            return href + param;
        else if (href.indexOf('?') > 0)
            return href + '&' + param;
        else
            return href + '?' + param;
    });
})
```

Comment: tested the script out. named anchors fail. links like "mysite.com/wiki/something" dont get appended....

Comment: For some reason this appends my key-value pair twice? Like: ?key=value&key=value

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution I put together for native Javascript, it supports existing query strings and anchors:

```
function addToQueryString(url, key, value) {
    var query = url.indexOf('?');
    var anchor = url.indexOf('#');
    if (query == url.length - 1) {
        // Strip any ? on the end of the URL
        url = url.substring(0, query);
        query = -1;
    }
    return (anchor > 0 ? url.substring(0, anchor) : url)
         + (query > 0 ? "&" + key + "=" + value : "?" + key + "=" + value)
         + (anchor > 0 ? url.substring(anchor) : "");
}
```

I've posted my existing tests on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/otapem/2/

Comment: Good solution, support anchor

Answer (score 2):

Taking what is above, this is the best way to concatenate parameters to links.

Also avoid link with href like href="Javascript:YourFunction();"

```
$(function(){                                      
   var myRandom = getRandom();       
   $('a[href]').each(function(i){
        var currHref = $(this).attr("href");
        var isAfunction = currHref.substring(0,10);              
        if(isAfunction == "javascript"){                
            $(this).attr("href",currHref);
        }else{
            if (currHref.charAt(currHref.length - 1) === '?')                           
                $(this).attr("href",currHref);
            else if (currHref.indexOf('?') > 0)                
                $(this).attr("href",currHref+"&rand="+getRandom());
            else                  
                $(this).attr("href",currHref+"?rand="+getRandom());
        }
   });               
});
function getRandom(){
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000); 
    return randomnumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a href must be full and corrected URL.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href]').attr('href', function(index, href) {
    var url = new URL(href);
    url.searchParams.set('ajax',1);
    return url;
  });
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtbjnaxf/2/)

Comment: Be aware that [searchParams still lacks browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams) so use with caution...