# Changing URL strings via JS on MediaWiki site

Tags: javascript, url, mediawiki

So...I've been setting up a brand-new wiki for the past four days. While everything's going almost smoothly, I'd like to deal with a special touchup.

I created a preload template à la Wikipedia, "Template starter", some hours ago. While I could go the other way and create an input form, I want to make it so that  red links in the Template namespace always lead to the code from this page, whenever a new one is ready for creation. So that:

> http://rfm.referata.com/w/index.php?title=Template:Foo&action=edit&redlink=1 (default)

becomes:

> http://rfm.referata.com/w/index.php?title=Template:Foo&action=edit&redlink=1&preload=Template:Template+starter (target)

by way of a JavaScript snippet added to the site's Common.js and Mobile.js.

Haven't come across similar MW-based examples, so I'd like to make sure everything's A-O.K.

Answer (score 1):

Working from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2667566/99667), you could do something like this in `Mediawiki:Common.js`:

```
$(function() {
    var preload = 'Template:Template_starter';
    $("body.ns-10 #mw-content-text a.new").attr('href', function(i, h) {
        // Maybe some links already have a preload parameter.
        if (h.indexOf('preload=') !== -1) {
            return h;
        }
        // All others get it appended.
        return h + "&preload=" + preload;
    });
});
```

Note that the check for a pre-existing '&preload=' isn't all that robust.

Answer (score 0):

This extension should work well in your case https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:NewArticleTemplate

Comment: Except that Referata--where my site's hosted--doesn't have it yet. May as well [request it](http://www.referata.com/wiki/Requested_features) when I find time; thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Improving on what you provided last time, Mr. Wilson:

```
$(function() {
var preload = 'Template:Template_starter';
$("a.new[href*='Template:']").attr('href', function(i, h) {
    // Maybe some links already have a preload parameter.
    if (h.indexOf('preload=') !== -1) {
        return h;
    }
    // All others get it appended.
    return h + "&preload=" + preload;
});
});
```

Note that the previous version only worked *within* pages in the Template namespace; this fix applies to all pages with a red link to a nonexistent template. Thanks a dozen!